# calculating probability distribution

Tags: math, statistics, probability, information-retrieval

I have a simple (may be stupid) question. I want to calculate Kullback–Leibler divergence on two documents. It requires probability distribution of each document.

I do not know how to calculate probability for each document. Any simple answer with layman example would be much appreciated.

Let's say we have follow two documents:

```
1 - cross validated answers are good 
2 - simply validated answers are nice
```

(wording of the documents is just bla bla to give you an example)

How do we calculate probabilities for these documents?

Let's say we add one more document:

```
3 - simply cross is not good answer
```

If we add another document then how would it impact probability distribution?

Thanks

Comment: it is not. In addition, I did not ask for source code ;). I asked for simple layman example. If it was homework my prof. would have explained me, lol

Comment: Kullback-Leibler divergence is not symmetric. It's possible that KL(D1, D2) != KL(D2, D1). Plus, if one of the documents contains a word that is not present in the other, you can get infinite divergence values (depends on the direction you measure the KL divergence). 

In case you want to compute the similarity of similarity of two documents with a measure that's based on information theory, I would suggest Jennsen-Shannon divergence (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen–Shannon_divergence) which is based on KL divergence, symmetric and finite.

Comment: I already know this, thanks anyways :-) I have specific reason to use KL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a document to a collection of documents, unless that document is exactly the same as the document collection, the distribution of words or terms in your distribution is going to change to accommodate the newly added words.  The question arises: "Is that really what you want to do with the third document?"

[Kullback-Leibler divergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) is a measure of divergence for two distributions.  What are you two distributions?

If your distribution is the probability of a certain word being selected at random in a document, then the space over which you have probability values is the collection of words which make up your documents.  For your first two documents (I assume this is your entire collection), you can build a word-space of 7 terms.  The Probability for a word being selected at random from the documents as bags of words are:

```
            doc 1     doc 2            doc 3   (lem)
answers      0.2       0.2              0.0     0.2
are          0.2       0.2              0.0     0.2
cross        0.2       0.0              .33     0.2
good         0.2       0.0              .33     0.2
nice         0.0       0.2              0.0     0.0
simply       0.0       0.2              .33     0.2
validated    0.2       0.2              0.0     0.0
```

[This is calculated as the term-frequency divided by the document lengths. Notice that the new document has word forms that aren't the same as the words in doc 1 and doc 2.  The (lem) column would be the probabilities if you stemmed or lemmatized to the same term the pairs (are/is) and (answer/answers).]

Introducing the third document into the scenario, a typical activity you might want to do with Kullback-Liebler Divergence is compare a new document or collection of documents with already-known documents or collections of documents.

Computing the Kullback-Liebler divergence `D(P||Q)` produces a value signifying how well the true distribution `P` is captured by using the substitute distribution `Q`.  So `Q1` could be the distribution of words in doc 1, and `Q2` could be the distribution of words in doc 2.  Computing the KL divergence with `P` being the distribution of words in the new document (doc 3), you can get measures of how divergent the new document is from doc 1 and how divergent it is from doc 2.  Using this information, you can say how similar the new document is to your know documents/collections.

Comment: Thank you so much Atreys for your detail/clear answer. I have a question here: what is the difference between TF and probability? it always confuses me. Can we use simple TF to calculate probability distribution of a document? I heard there are some ways to normalise a document for probability distribution, do you have any idea what is it (normalization)?

Comment: Term frequency is the frequency of terms in a document.  If the term "dog" appears three times in a document, then the term frequency is 3.  If the document has 8000 terms in it, the probability of the term being chosen at random from the document is 3/8000.  For IR, a more useful calculation is TF-IDF, which is Term-frequency over document frequency.  If the term "dog" only appears 8 times in your corpus, then the TF-IDF is going to be 3/8 -- potentially highly significant, if you have a hundred or so documents.  The probability distribution I showed was the probability of a ...

Comment: ... term being chosen from a document if you were choosing words by just going to a random indexed word in the document and looking at it.  Dividing the TF by the document length is what I did.  That's the normalization used in probability vectors: divide the vector by the sum of the components, so everything adds up to 1.  If you haven't a book on information retrieval, I found [Introduction to Information Retrieval](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/information-retrieval-book.html) to be very accessible as an easy to follow intro to the field.

Comment: Thanks, so you mean that TF and probability is same in IR? For example dog word 3/8000 is TF as well as the probability? thanks for the book link.

Comment: No.  3 is the TF of "dog" in the given document. 3/8000 was the [TF-IDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) of the term "dog" in the given document when taking the collection of documents into consideration.